# How to interrupt Eclipse RCP shutdown

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, application-shutdown

I have a plugin into an eclipse rcp application.  I need to detect a scenario whenever a particular perspective is closed or if the application is closed and based on the outcome, I may need to cancel the closing of the app or perspective.  If I had access to the application's WorkbenchAdvisor class, this would be trivial.  As a plugin to this app, how can I detect the event and how can I tell the main application/advisor that I need to have the close canceled?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at installing an [IWorkbenchListener](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchListener.html) and extending the `preShutdown` method? It appears you can veto a shutdown using this mechanism.

Comment: That works great for capturing the workbench shutdown when the app closes and may indeed be what I'm stuck with.  I can't find anything to detect AND veto the closing of a perspective.  I can use an IPerspectiveListener3 to detect the close, but it doesn't allow it to be canceled.

Answer (score 0):

I think want you want to do is not possible. If a plug-in could prevent an rcp application to shut down (or the other way force it to should down) this can be a serious security problem. Also the app state would be unclear as it might has released some resources.

If an app wants to give control of program termination to a plug-in it should define an interface/extension point that can be used.